# How to write UPDATE based on MAX?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here is simplified example of my 2 tables from MS SQL 2008 database

```
Documents [Id] AND 
DocumentsVersions [Id, DocumentId, IsCancelled]
```

I want to add column IsActual (Bit NOT NULL) to DocumentVersions that will represent if that version is the most actual. I check whether DocumentVersion is actual or not by checking if its Id is highest from non-cancelled versions of the same Document.

I am able to write SELECT query:

```
SELECT [t2].[Id] AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT MAX([t0].[Id]) AS [value], [t0].[DocumentId]
    FROM [DocumentVersions] AS [t0]
    WHERE NOT ([t0].[IsCancelled] = 1)
    GROUP BY [t0].[DocumentId]
    ) AS [t1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [DocumentVersions] AS [t2] ON ([t2].[Id] = [t1].[value]) 
     AND ([t1].[DocumentId] = [t2].[DocumentId]) 
     AND (NOT ([t2].[IsCancelled] = 1))
```

How to write update query that will set IsActual = 1 to records that meet these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out following using CTE:

```
;WITH maxNotCancelled(id)
AS
(
    SELECT [t2].[Id] AS [value]
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX([t0].[Id]) AS [value], [t0].[DocumentId]
        FROM [DocumentVersions] AS [t0]
        WHERE NOT ([t0].[IsCancelled] = 1)
        GROUP BY [t0].[DocumentId]
        ) AS [t1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [DocumentVersions] AS [t2] ON ([t2].[Id] = [t1].[value]) 
         AND ([t1].[DocumentId] = [t2].[DocumentId]) 
         AND (NOT ([t2].[IsCancelled] = 1))
)
UPDATE DocumentVersion
  SET d.IsActual = 1
FROM DocumentVersion d 
INNER JOIN maxNotCancelled m ON m.id = d.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DocumentVersions dv
SET IsActual = 1 
WHERE dv.IsCancelled = 0
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM DocumentVersions nx
    WHERE nx.DocumentId = dv.DocumentId
      AND nx.IsCancelled = 0
      AND nx.id > dv.id -- assuming incrementing IDs
    );
```